# My assignment is to Create a file with comma seperated random numbers. Write python code to sum and average of them. How to do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = ("random_numbers", "r+")
a = int(input("How many number do want to input? Type 0 to exit:"))

sum = 0
count = 0
number = 0

for i in range(a):
    x = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    n.write(str(x) + str(','))
    sum = sum + number
    count += 1

average = sum/count

n.write('the sum of the numbers is' + sum)
n.write('the average of the numbers is' + average)
n.seek(0)
n.read()
n.close()
```

This code when it is run shows the error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: You must open a file in order to write to it. Just stating the arguments to open creates a tuple of the arguments, it does not call the open function. n = open("random_numbers", "w")

Answer (score 0):

you can use [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to generate your random numbers:

```
import random

a = int(input("How many number do want to input?"))

with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as fp:
    my_numbers = random.sample(range(1000), a)
    fp.write(','.join(map(str, my_numbers)))
    fp.write( '\nthe sum of the numbers is ' + str(sum(my_numbers)))
    fp.write( '\nthe average of the numbers is ' + str(sum(my_numbers) / len(my_numbers)))
```

in the above example if you have `a` > 1000 this code will not work, another way to generate your random numbers is:

```
import random

a = int(input("How many number do want to input?"))

with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as fp:
    my_numbers = [random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(a)]
    fp.write(','.join(map(str, my_numbers)))
    fp.write( '\nthe sum of the numbers is ' + str(sum(my_numbers)))
    fp.write( '\nthe average of the numbers is ' + str(sum(my_numbers) / len(my_numbers)))
```

using [random.randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)